# Search Dialog on android doesn't appear at all. How do I inflate it, the box doesn't show up?

Tags: android, xml, search, dialog, android-manifest

I followed this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html
I really don't know what to do. Does the search dialog need inflating? I didn't write anything related to the search box on the Register activity where I want it to appear so is that the problem? There is nothing showing up, no search box no dialog no nothing.

And one more question, in case I make this work eventually, could I set the Register activity to also handle the searching part, basically move the Searchable activity code over to the Register activity? I only need to perform the search on the Register activity once and I would prefer if it would display a list view on the Register activity itself. Then the user could select a value from that list view (which would be populated from a mysql server database) and the value is put in a string which used to register the user.

Searchable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                   android:value=".SearchableActivity" />

        </activity>
<activity
            android:name=".SearchableActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_searchable" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```

Strings:

```
<string name="search_hint">Google sucks</string>
<string name="app_name">I hate android</string>
```

Searchable activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class SearchableActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchable);
        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        handleIntent(getIntent());

    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          //doMySearch(query);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From your provided link.. "*So when using the search dialog, you must provide a search button in your UI that activates the search dialog by calling onSearchRequested()*"

Comment: Yeah, I read that too, but they way I interpreted was that it isn't strictly necessary. Plus they didn't really write any example code and I don't know how to use that onSearchRequested() method. I think I will just use a simple button combined with a regular edittext box instead of crappy overcomplicated search solutions from google. Might even look nicer like that.

Comment: I used the search widget and it's pretty sophisticated if you ask me. Just had to added an icon to the actionbar. You can try calling onSearchRequested() inside of your activity just to try if it works tho.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing most important thing in that guide .And Yes, search dialog need inflating.

I think you have not seen full tutorial in the guide.
Check creating a search widget in the link you posted.They have given an example code.

You can have more info regarding your problem in this [sample-Seachable Dictionary](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html)

Comment: Search widget works only with devices that have at least SDK 11, android 3.0. I want to make the app for older devices as well. That link takes me to http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html, which is a confusing thing. It doesn't send me to download exactly the sample. Maybe I am missing something but I see no download link. This is why I hate the resources from google. Anyway I am using a simple editText with a button. I don't think I am missing anything with this approach. Don't really know waht the advantage to a search dialog is anyway.

Comment: Yeah it's getting redirected .Check [this](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/3.0/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html) If you are not using search widget then you can get the search string directly from editext,why are you bothering to searchmanager ?

Comment: Thank you. I don't have that much experience with programming so the search box was the first thing that came to mind for what I needed. Didn't think it would be so complicated. Then I realized I could probably do what I need without the searchmanager.